# selenium WebDriverWait for element to appear is timed out despite of the element being present

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to switch to iframe, I'm also making sure to wait for the iframe to be loaded, I can see the iframe in the DOM but it says no element found and getting timed out.

DOM:

[image]

I tried this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).
   until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='dom-distiller-result-iframe']")
))
```

alternately I tried this:

```
time.sleep(10)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='dom-distiller-result-iframe']"))
```

Console:
[image]

Comment: What website is it on?

Comment: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/add.14031
I'm using dom-distiller extension and this extension will add the iframe at the bottom of the page

Comment: If you print the page_source does it come up?

Comment: In dev tools it will. in the page source it wont because this new iframe is added after i click the extension(through automation). However, it is printing the element id and tagname but it is failing to switch to it. BTW, it is switching sometimes and sometimes i'm getting the error

Comment: Try increasing the wait time.

Comment: Tried. Kept in a loop with try except and tried multiple times no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try the following id tag.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'dom-distiller-result-iframe')))
```

Comment: Same error. I even tried to print the element and id 
`ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='dom-distiller-result-iframe']")
print(ele.get_attribute('id'))
print(ele.tag_name) `  i'm getting "dom-distiller-result-iframe" and "iframe"